# When load a dump into a database, it issues: #1100 - Table 'pma__column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I load a dump into database, It issue:

```
#1100 - Table 'pma__column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

Tell me, please, how can I solve this problem?

PS: where? how? and what tables should I disable?

Comment: I'm curious if the .sql file you're importing has any references to the `pma__column_info` table or `phpmyadmin` database?

Comment: No. The database is empty - 11 original tables. Missing tables should be created in the database itself, isn't it?

Comment: A missing table *may* be created by the .sql file, but it doesn't have to be; however your error message isn't about a missing table but rather about some trouble with the database phpMyAdmin uses to track some internal metadata and enable advanced features. In your database list (on the left hand navigation screen) do you see a table called phpmyadmin? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: Ok. yes, there is database "phpMyAdmin" in the database list.And mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20